# Inno Setup: How to run a postback script depending on user options?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to have a postback script run for when someone installs my program with Inno Setup. As far as I know, I can just use the [Run] section to run a url file like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\postback.url";
```

However, how do I pass different postback scripts based on what the user chose during installation? I have a few components, and I'd like to know which components were installed. Are there any "if" statements or something?

Also, is there a better way to do the postback function? I feel like there should be something easier than running a .url file.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

See the [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) examples folder, in particular the CodeDlg.iss and CodeExample1.iss scripts. They both show how to use the `[Code]` section, and the first shows how to create dialog pages that get custom user feedback.

Also see the `Pascal Scripting` section at the [Inno Setup Help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) pages.

Comment: Sorry, that's still a bit confusing for me. If component "A" is chosen, I need to run a file in the [Run] section. The only problem is that the [Run] section doesn't support "Component:" or "Types:". What's the way around this? Thanks for your help, sir.

Comment: Apparantly the Run section DOES support Components... did you know that? =)